# Search in List; Display names based on search input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have sought different articles here about searching data from a list, but nothing seems to be working right or is appropriate in what I am supposed to implement.

I have this pre-created module with over 500 list (they are strings, yes, but is considered as list when called into function; see code below) of names, city, email, etc. The following are just a chunk of it.

```
empRecords="""Jovita,Oles,8 S Haven St,Daytona Beach,Volusia,FL,6/14/1965,32114,386-248-4118,386-208-6976,joles@gmail.com,http://www.paganophilipgesq.com,;
Alesia,Hixenbaugh,9 Front St,Washington,District of Columbia,DC,3/3/2000,20001,202-646-7516,202-276-6826,alesia_hixenbaugh@hixenbaugh.org,http://www.kwikprint.com,;
Lai,Harabedian,1933 Packer Ave #2,Novato,Marin,CA,1/5/2000,94945,415-423-3294,415-926-6089,lai@gmail.com,http://www.buergimaddenscale.com,;
Brittni,Gillaspie,67 Rv Cent,Boise,Ada,ID,11/28/1974,83709,208-709-1235,208-206-9848,bgillaspie@gillaspie.com,http://www.innerlabel.com,;
Raylene,Kampa,2 Sw Nyberg Rd,Elkhart,Elkhart,IN,12/19/2001,46514,574-499-1454,574-330-1884,rkampa@kampa.org,http://www.hermarinc.com,;
Flo,Bookamer,89992 E 15th St,Alliance,Box Butte,NE,12/19/1957,69301,308-726-2182,308-250-6987,flo.bookamer@cox.net,http://www.simontonhoweschneiderpc.com,;
Jani,Biddy,61556 W 20th Ave,Seattle,King,WA,8/7/1966,98104,206-711-6498,206-395-6284,jbiddy@yahoo.com,http://www.warehouseofficepaperprod.com,;
Chauncey,Motley,63 E Aurora Dr,Orlando,Orange,FL,3/1/2000,32804,407-413-4842,407-557-8857,chauncey_motley@aol.com,http://www.affiliatedwithtravelodge.com
"""

a = empRecords.strip().split(";")
```

And I have the following code for searching:

```
import empData as x

def seecity():
    empCitylist = list()
    for ct in x.a:
        empCt = ct.strip().split(",")
        empCitylist.append(empCt)
    t = sorted(empCitylist, key=lambda x: x[3])
    for c in t:
        city = (c[3])
        print(city)
        live_city = input("Enter city: ")
        for cy in city:
            if live_city in cy:
                print(c[1])

         # print("Name: "+ c[1] + ",", c[0], "| Current City: " + c[3])
```

Forgive my idiotic approach as I am new to Python. However, what I am trying to do is user will input the city, then the results should display the employee's last name, first name who are living in that city (I dunno if I made sense lol)

By the way, the code I used above doesn't return any answers. It just loops to the input.

Thank you for helping. Lovelots. <3

PS: the format of the empData is: first name, last name, address, city, country, birthday, zip, phone, and email

Comment: what you posted is a string but you are saying "500 list of names"? Can you clarify this? does the string is a single element in the list?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is a string yes, but should be considered as a list when called in a function.

Comment: what do you mean by consider string as a list? and what is your goal exactly?

Comment: If you can see the code above I am converting it into a list: 

`def seecity():
    empCitylist = list()
    for ct in x.a:
        empCt = ct.strip().split(",")`

My goal here now as I have mentioned is to display the employees living in the city, which is the input of the user.

Say for example, if I placed "Orange" in the input, it should display those employees who lives in Orange. Did I make sense?

Comment: Do I need to post my whole code just so you can have a better grip on what I am trying to say about considering the string as a list?

Comment: what is in `x.a` can you share that?

Comment: @komatiraju032 `a = empRecords.strip().split(";")`

Comment: @komatiraju032 `import empData as x` `a = empRecords.strip().split(";")`

Comment: Could you please mention which one is first name, last name, city in "Jovita,Oles,8 S Haven St,Daytona Beach,Volusia,FL,6/14/1965,32114,386-248-4118,386-208-6976,joles@gmail.com,http://www.paganophilipgesq.com"  this line.

Is that like 
first name: Jovita,
last name: Oles,
city: 8 S Haven St,Daytona Beach,Volusia,FL,6/14/1965,32114,386-248-4118,386-208-6976,
email: joles@gmail.com,
website: http://www.paganophilipgesq.com

Comment: Oh sure, the format is: first name, last name, address, city, country, so on and forth. :)

Comment: @Gaaaaaab instead of splitting the `ct` you can directly check `live_city.lower()  in ct.lower()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your original code, you can do it like this:

```
# Make list of list records, sorted by city
t = sorted((ct.strip().split(",") for ct in x.a), key=lambda x: x[3])

# List cities
print("Cities in DB:")
for c in t:
    city = (c[3])
    print("-", city)

# Define search function
def seecity():
    live_city = input("Enter city: ")
    for c in t:
        if live_city == c[3]:
            print("Name: "+ c[1] + ",", c[0], "| Current City: " + c[3])

seecity()
```

Then, after you understand what's going on, do as @Hoxha Alban suggested, and use the `csv` module.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. It works well, except it only displays one name and not the rest of those who live in the same city. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: As you can see, the code does not contain any limitation on the number of entries printed (no condition to stop the loop, or `break` statement). The sample database does not contain duplicates that I can see, so my testing did not show multiple outputs for a search term.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csv module to read easily a file with comma separated values

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    records = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

def search(data, elem, index): 
    out = list()
    for row in data:
        if row[index] == elem:
            out.append(row)
    return out

#test
print(search(records, 'Orlando', 3))
```

Comment: CSV is kind of advanced for me as I tried to do that prior to creating a module for empData. But I will try to study that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of python lies in list comprehension.

```
empRecords="""Jovita,Oles,8 S Haven St,Daytona Beach,Volusia,FL,6/14/1965,32114,386-248-4118,386-208-6976,joles@gmail.com,http://www.paganophilipgesq.com,;
Alesia,Hixenbaugh,9 Front St,Washington,District of Columbia,DC,3/3/2000,20001,202-646-7516,202-276-6826,alesia_hixenbaugh@hixenbaugh.org,http://www.kwikprint.com,;
Lai,Harabedian,1933 Packer Ave #2,Novato,Marin,CA,1/5/2000,94945,415-423-3294,415-926-6089,lai@gmail.com,http://www.buergimaddenscale.com,;
Brittni,Gillaspie,67 Rv Cent,Boise,Ada,ID,11/28/1974,83709,208-709-1235,208-206-9848,bgillaspie@gillaspie.com,http://www.innerlabel.com,;
Raylene,Kampa,2 Sw Nyberg Rd,Elkhart,Elkhart,IN,12/19/2001,46514,574-499-1454,574-330-1884,rkampa@kampa.org,http://www.hermarinc.com,;
Flo,Bookamer,89992 E 15th St,Alliance,Box Butte,NE,12/19/1957,69301,308-726-2182,308-250-6987,flo.bookamer@cox.net,http://www.simontonhoweschneiderpc.com,;
Jani,Biddy,61556 W 20th Ave,Seattle,King,WA,8/7/1966,98104,206-711-6498,206-395-6284,jbiddy@yahoo.com,http://www.warehouseofficepaperprod.com,;
Chauncey,Motley,63 E Aurora Dr,Orlando,Orange,FL,3/1/2000,32804,407-413-4842,407-557-8857,chauncey_motley@aol.com,http://www.affiliatedwithtravelodge.com
"""

rows  = empRecords.strip().split(";")
data = [ r.strip().split(",") for r in rows ]
```

then you can use any condition to filter the list, like

```
print ( [ "Name: " + emp[1] + "," + emp[0] + "| Current City: " + emp[3] for emp in data if emp[3] == "Washington" ] )
['Name: Hixenbaugh,Alesia| Current City: Washington']
```